# How to mix images and movies with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a bunch if h264 encoded mp4 files (of about 10-15 seconds) and I want to mix them with another bunch of jpegs (which should be displayed for x seconds each).
So I've setup the concat.txt file :

```
file slide_1.jpg
duration 3
file movie_1.mp4
file slide_2.jpg
duration 5
file movie_2.mp4
```

and I am trying to run

```
yes | scripts/ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -vcodec copy -c:a copy final.mp4
```

which generates a movie with the length of 6 hours (6:48:34) and in which I can only see the 1st picture.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: The concat demuxer requires that all inputs be the same codec, so you would have to make movies from the images first, or somehow do it via filtering.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. I saw in the docs that all pieces have to be in the same codec, but I've never realized that - indeed - even the pics have to be converted to a movie first. I will try then post here.

Comment: Ok it works, thx.! Would you make it into a proper answer so I can validate it, or should I ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As LordNeckbeard said, the slides should first be converted to movies first.

So in my case I convert the slide to movie like this (slide 1 will be a 3 seconds clip):

```
yes | scripts/ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 25 -i slide_1.jpg -t 00:00:03 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -an slide_1.mp4
```

Then the concat file looks like this:

```
file slide_1.mp4
file movie_1.mp4
file slide_2.mp4
file movie_2.mp4
```

and the concatenation command is:

```
yes | scripts/ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -vcodec copy -c:a copy final.mp4
```

Note that all the movie pieces must be of the same width and height